# Popen execution error

Tags: python

This is how my code looks and I get an error, while using Popen

test.py

```
import subprocess
import sys

def test(jobname):
    print jobname
    p=subprocess.Popen([sys.executable,jobname,parm1='test',parm2='test1'])


if __name__ == "__main__":
   test(r'C:\Python27\test1.py')
```

test1.py

```
def test1(parm1,parm2):
  print 'test1',parm1

if __name__ = '__main__':
  test1(parm1='',parm2='')
```

Error

Syntax error

Answer (score 4):

**In test1.py:**

You need two equal signs in :

```
if __name__ = '__main__':
```

Use instead

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

since you want to compare the value of `__name__` with the string `'__main__'`, not assign a value to `__name__`.

---

**In test.py:**

`parm1='test'` is a SyntaxError. You can not to assign a value to a variable in the middle of a list:

```
p=subprocess.Popen([sys.executable,jobname,parm1='test',parm2='test1'])
```

---

It appears you want to feed different values for `parm1` and `parm2` into the function `test1.test1`. You can not do that by calling `python test1.py` since there `parm1=''` and `parm2=''` are hard-coded there.

When you want to run a non-Python script from Python, use `subprocess`. But when you want to run Python functions in a subprocess, use [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html):

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import test1

def test(function, *args, **kwargs):
    print(function.__name__)
    proc = mp.Process(target = function, args = args, kwargs = kwargs)
    proc.start()
    proc.join()  # wait for proc to end

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test(test1.test1, parm1 = 'test', parm2 = 'test1')
```

Comment: It should probably be `Popen([sys.executable, jobname, 'test', 'test1'])`. test1.py needs to use `sys.argv`.

Comment: @eryksun: Thanks; you are absolutely right. In that case, I think multiprocessing in test.py would be cleaner than changing test1.py. Editing...